# Automatically start SMTP server in IIS?

Tags: iis, smtp

I'm running an IIS SMTP server in Windows 2008 R2 and it can be started manually. However, if I need to restart the system, I must manually start the SMTP server.

Is there a way for it to start automatically on boot?

Thanks

Answer (score 42):

Open the `run` dialog on the server, and enter `services.msc`.  Locate the 'Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP)' service, right click, choose `Properties` and set the service to `Automatic`.  From now on, it will start at boot

Comment: There is no SMTP service...

Comment: Look for "Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP)".

Comment: Also, you need to make sure the feature is installed

Answer (score 19):

The display name in the services list is "Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP)"

Set the Startup Type to Automatic

You may also want to select the Recovery tab and set the service to restart on failures.

Comment: And to think I spent a good 15 minutes looking for "SMTP" in that list...

Answer (score -3):

Scheduled Tasks, Run on boot. That's will accomplish what you're looking for.